# In Angular Typescript how to create a Observable from Map()

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a contact service that is responsible for managing contacts, in a address book, type of way. for example my interface looks like this:

```js
export interface AddressBook {
  a?: Contact[];
  //...
}
```

and `Contact[]` is just stuff like name, age, email.
In my service I currently have this implementation:

```js
  private addressBook: Map<string, Contact[]> = new Map<string, Contact[]>();
  private readonly ab$: BehaviorSubject<string | Contact[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string | Contact[]>(this.addressBook);

  public constructor(){}

  public getContacts(): Observable<string | Contact[]> {
    return this.ab$.asObservable();
  }
```

however the problem that I am getting is with the `private readonly ab$: BehaviorSubject<string | Contact[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string | Contact[]>(this.addressBook)`  where it says:

> not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Contact[]'.
>     Type 'Map' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 21 more.ts(2345)

I cannot see where this error is coming from. Thank you guys for any help!

Comment: Do not do this `new BehaviorSubject(this.addressBook)`. You will trigger *this expression has changed* errors in Angular, and it is also an anti-pattern in functional programming.

Comment: what would be the better way to do this? the articles that I have read have the `new BehaviorSubject(this.addressBook)`

Comment: @Ctfrancia maybe you can leave out the whole BehaviorSubject part and directly access the addressBook.

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look at that @robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BehaviourSubject` should be instantiated as follows:

```
private readonly ab$: BehaviorSubject<Map<string, Contact[]>> = new BehaviorSubject(new Map({}));
```

Since it has to be same type as `addressBook`.